# How to determine width on responsive scroll menu

Tags: html, css

I'm using this [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_menu_horizontal_scroll.asp) to build scrolling menu once the screen size is smaller.

I also want to add border with width element, but once I define width the `scrolling: auto;` element is override. My target is creating border with width and still keep the scrolling auto element working once the screen is minimized.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/yotking789/pen/WNbqMjO) with width defined

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/yotking789/pen/oNgrEWK) with undefined width

```css
.scrollmenu-container{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
}
div.scrollmenu {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
}

div.scrollmenu a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: grey;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

div.scrollmenu a:hover {
  color: #24d175;
}
```

```html
        <div class="scrollmenu-container">
          <div class="scrollmenu">
              <a>הכל</a>
              <a>USB</a>
              <a>מטענים</a>
              <a>מתאמים</a>
              <a>גדאג'טים למחשב'</a>
          </div>
        </div>
```

How can I define width for border without override scrolling auto element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a specific width to .scrollmenu class and use `overflow-X: scroll;` in media query for small devices. I have added media query for mobile devices.
Hope this Helps.

```css
.scrollmenu-container{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
}
div.scrollmenu {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
  
}

div.scrollmenu a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: grey;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

div.scrollmenu a:hover {
  color: #24d175;
}

@media (max-width:767px){
  div.scrollmenu{max-width:300px; overflow-X: scroll;}
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollmenu-container">
          <div class="scrollmenu">
              <a>הכל</a>
              <a>USB</a>
              <a>מטענים</a>
              <a>מתאמים</a>
              <a>גדאג'טים למחשב'</a>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.scrollmenu-container{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
}
div.scrollmenu {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
}

div.scrollmenu a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: grey;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

div.scrollmenu a:hover {
  color: #24d175;
}
.menu-wrapper{
  width:100%;
  overflow:auto;
}

<div class="menu-wrapper">  
<div class="scrollmenu-container">
          <div class="scrollmenu">
              <a>הכל</a>
              <a>USB</a>
              <a>מטענים</a>
              <a>מתאמים</a>
              <a>גדאג'טים למחשב'</a>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

May be those code snippets help your question. I put a wrapper around menu and set a style for it. It scrolls when page size gets smaller.